# Multi Splines on Chart Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i am using Splines chart of Asp.net.  i want to use Multi Splines on Chart Control

```
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="1200" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Spline" XValueMember="abc" YValueMembers="Expr1"></asp:Series>

        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Just add another `Series`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally! i did it as mentioned below

```
string seriesName = "TestRuns";
Chart1.Series.Add(seriesName);
Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
Chart1.Series[seriesName].YValueMembers = "TestRunsDatafield";
Chart1.Series[seriesName].XValueMember = "date1";

string seriesName = "ODIRuns";
Chart1.Series.Add(seriesName);
Chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
Chart1.Series[seriesName].YValueMembers = "ODIRunsDataFiels";
Chart1.Series[seriesName].XValueMember = "date1";
```